# AngularJS - handle click events on existing DOM elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, dom-events

I'm trying to capture a click event on a selection of existing DOM items using Angular:

[image: (node tree on the left)]

Here's the code:

```
<!-- 
HTML template (section) - it's a django template, i kept the 
django template syntax as original, using '{{' and '}}', and for 
AngularJS templating's system '{$' and '$}'
-->
<fieldset class="module aligned">
    <h2>Document's sections</h2>

    <div class="form-row document-nodes" ng-app="DocumentNodesApp">
        <div style="width: 100%; min-height: 450px;"
             ng-controller="NodeController" on-node-click="getNodeTitle($event)">
            <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
                <div id="tree"
                     data-url="{{ tree_json_url }}"
                     data-save_state="{{ app_label }}_documentnode"
                     data-auto_open="{{ tree_auto_open }}"
                     data-autoescape="{{ autoescape }}"
                >
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="node-container">
                {$node_title$}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>


/* DocumentNodeApp js code */

var app = angular.module('DocumentNodesApp', []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});

var nodeController = app.controller(
        'NodeController',
        function($scope){
             $scope.node_title = "Click on a node...";
             $scope.getNodeTitle = function(event){
                 alert(event);
             }

        });
app.directive(
    "onNodeClick", function(selector, $parse){
        // connect the Angular context to the DOM events
        var linkFunction = function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            //get the scope expression, will be evaluated on
            // the scope when the document is clicked
            var scopeExpression = $attrs.onNodeClick;

            var invoker = $parse(scopeExpression);

            $(selector).on("click", function(event){
               $scope.$apply(
                   function(){
                       invoker(
                           $scope, { $event: event}
                       )
                   }
               );
            });
        }
        return( linkFunction );
    }
);
```

After reloading the page, I have this error in console:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/$injector/unpr?p0=selectorProvider%20%3C-%20selector%20%3C-%20onNodeClickDirective
    at Error (native)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8050/sitestatic/js/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://127.0.0.1:8050/sitestatic/js/angular.min.js:38:60
    at Object.d [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:8050/sitestatic/js/angular.min.js:36:74)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8050/sitestatic/js/angular.min.js:38:132
    at d (http://127.0.0.1:8050/sitestatic/js/angular.min.js:36:74)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://127.0.0.1:8050/sitestatic/js/angular.min.js:36:335)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8050/sitestatic/js/angular.min.js:47:393
    at r (http://127.0.0.1:8050/sitestatic/js/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8050/sitestatic/js/angular.min.js:47:360) angular.min.js:101
```

Anyone has an idea of how to solve it? I just followed [this guide](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2422-capturing-document-click-events-with-angularjs.htm) on how to handle click events with AngularJS but it seems that doesn't work for me.

Comment: In your directive, you need to change "selector" to "$document" 1) function argument 2)  $(selector) to $document

Comment: ok, and where i have to put the class selector for the dom elemets that i want?

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to capture clicks on specific child elements of the element your `on-node-click` directive is attached to, you would, in your directive definition, attach the click listener to that element, and use the optional `selector` parameter in jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to filter for just the child elements you want. You don't need to deal with `$document` at all.

So your directive would look like this:

```
.directive('onNodeClick', ['$parse', function ($parse) {    
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var scopeExpresssion = attrs.onNodeClick, // gets string 'getNodeTitle($event)' from element attribute            
          invoker = $parse(scopeExpresssion); // compile string into a function

      // listen for clicks on .node child elements
      element.on('click', '.node', function (e) {
        // wrap the function invocation in scope.$apply() so angular knows about it
        scope.$apply(function () {
          invoker(scope, { $event: e });
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmwko3at/1/).

If, however, you really do need to capture click events on the document node like that article discusses, you just need to inject `$document` into your directive and attach the click listener to that instead of to the element that your directive is on.

In that case, your directive would look like this:

```
.directive('onNodeClick', ['$document', '$parse', function ($document, $parse) {    
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var scopeExpresssion = attrs.onNodeClick, // gets string 'getNodeTitle($event)' from element attribute            
          invoker = $parse(scopeExpresssion); // compile string into a function

      // listen for clicks on all .node elements within document
      $document.on('click', '.node', function (e) {
        // wrap the function invocation in scope.$apply() so angular knows about it
        scope.$apply(function () {
          invoker(scope, { $event: e });
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```